# Swift Package access modifiers

Tags: swift, access-modifiers, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I created a simply `Swift Package` with one `UI class` in it.

I managed to upload to a repo and use it in a project.

First time when I tried to import it and use it in a main project there was a problem with access modifiers because my `package` was `not public` but defined as `class MainView: UIView {}`.

After I've changed my package to `public class MainView: UIView {}` it worked well.

My question:

**Isn't the package like any other of my project classes? Why is supposed to be used with `public`?**

**Is there any way to use my package classes without the `public access modifier`?**

Comment: the public is required because your package class is outside the target module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default access modifier is "internal" which indicates that it's within the project itself. A Swift package (framework) is a 3rd party "project" that you implement nested inside your project. Which means you are trying to reach code from another project.

TL;DR, No you can not skip using public access modifiers if you want to reach the functionality

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 5.9, `package` access modifier [was added](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0386-package-access-modifier.md).